# Unable to delete CloudFormation stack that defines a Lambda-backed custom resource

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I created an *AWS Lambda* function using *NodeJS* to create VPC flow logs. This *Lambda* will be triggered by *AWS CloudFormation* every time I touch the custom resource.

My question:
When I delete the *CloudFormation* stack, the Lambda function does not send a proper response back to *CloudFormation*, and since the stack is not getting deleted, it's reflecting back with this error:

**Custom Resource failed to stabilize in expected time**

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

since custom resource using lambda function i have written sample script to give the response back as success 
since my requirement is creating NAT gateway using custom resource the sample delete function is as follows

```
 var deleteflowlogs = function(event, context) {
    var responseData = {};
    if (event.PhysicalResourceId && event.PhysicalResourceId.match(/^nat-/)) {
        console.log("in delete flow logs");
        ec2.deleteFlowLogs({
            FlowLogIds: [event.PhysicalResourceId]
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                responseData = {
                    Error: "delete flowlogs failed " + err
                };
                console.log(responseData.Error);
                response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, responseData, event.PhysicalResourceId);
            } else {
                response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {}, event.PhysicalResourceId)
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log("No valid physical resource id passed to destroy - ignoring " + event.PhysicalResourceId);
        response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData, event.PhysicalResourceId);
    }
}
```